# Super simple accordion menu with open/close icon

Tags: jquery, accordion

I am using simple accordion which works perfectly, the only need is to show open/closed icon. Have no idea how to add/remove class to parent item which will interact with accordion state, so need your help.

```
<!-- JS -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($) {
$('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

  //Expand or collapse this panel
  $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

  //Hide the other panels
  $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

});
});
</script>

<!-- CSS -->
<style>
.accordion-toggle {cursor: pointer;}
.accordion-content {display: none;}
.accordion-content.default {display: block;}
</style>

<!-- HTML -->
<div id="accordion">
<h4 class="accordion-toggle">Accordion 1</h4>
<div class="accordion-content default">
<p>Cras malesuada ultrices augue molestie risus.</p>
</div>
<h4 class="accordion-toggle">Accordion 2</h4>
<div class="accordion-content">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet mauris eu turpis.</p>
</div>
<h4 class="accordion-toggle">Accordion 3</h4>
<div class="accordion-content">
<p>Vivamus facilisisnibh scelerisque laoreet.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using jQuery UI for accordion ?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned hiding/showing icons but at the end, you really wanted a guide on how to:

> "add/remove class to parent item which will interact with accordion
>   state"

I'm therefore assuming that you intend to use classes to interchangeably display a 'collapsed' and 'expanded' icon to a clicked parent item.

EDIT: based on your clarification, I've modified the code.  Please see the sample code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {

//adds the "collapsed" class to each parent
$('#accordion .accordion-toggle').addClass('collapsed'); 

$('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){
  //Expand or collapse this panel
  $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
  
  //toggles between collapsed and expanded classes
$(this).toggleClass('collapsed expanded');
  
  //removes any instance of "expanded" from the other parents and replace it with the "collapsed" class
     $("#accordion .accordion-toggle").not($(this)).removeClass('expanded').addClass('collapsed');
  
  //Hide the other panels
  $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');  

});
});
```

```css
.expanded {
  background:red;
}

.collapsed {
  background:blue;
}
.accordion-content:not(.default) {
  display:none;
}
h4 {
  cursor:pointer;
}
/* the css below is unnecessary for the accordion, but just to prevent the vertical scrollbars from showing up using stackoverflow's code screen */ 
body {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
<h4 class="accordion-toggle">Accordion 1</h4>
<div class="accordion-content default">
<p>Cras malesuada ultrices augue molestie risus.</p>
</div>
<h4 class="accordion-toggle">Accordion 2</h4>
<div class="accordion-content">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet mauris eu turpis.</p>
</div>
<h4 class="accordion-toggle">Accordion 3</h4>
<div class="accordion-content">
<p>Vivamus facilisisnibh scelerisque laoreet.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. Checked your example and i see, that expanded/collapsed class doesn't change when I click on the same parent item.

Comment: I just checked the fiddle and it works fine from my end. Maybe the issue is on the visual cue? As such, I added an additional styling that changes the cursor on hover over the parent item.  Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0ggq6w77/3/

Comment: Please let me explain, we have three tabs: Accordion 1, Accordion 2, Accordion 3. If we open and close the same Accordion 1 several times, class doesn't change, it still remains <h4 class="accordion-toggle expanded">. Could you please modify it so each time we open/close even the same accordion tab, class will change from expanded to collapsed? Now class changes only if we open another tab.

Comment: Ah, I see. I've edited my answer to accommodate the spec you mentioned.  Is this what you needed?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! The only thing, previously I added "default" class with display: block to the first item, so it will be expanded. Now it doesn't work, how it can be fixed?

Comment: can you go to jsfiddle and put your code there so that I can take a look at it?

Comment: I used the same code, just added css class and styling: .accordion-content.default {display: block;}

Comment: Got it. Just use a :not selector in your CSS to exclude (from being displayed-none) those that have the "default" class. It's important to remember that in this case, your CSS styles determine the initial display of the accordion. See my updated answer.

Comment: @LifeIsShort - if your issue has been resolved, would you mind accepting my answer? Thanks,